# Passing a List From the MainActivity to a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have a `viewPager` activity that makes multiple fragments with custom `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

I need to get the `List<Audio> audioList` and use it in my `fragment`.

Here is a small part of my `MainActivity` where I make the `fragments`. I do not think the rest of the MainActivity code is required in order to answer this question.

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter =
            new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this, audioList);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
```

Here is my custom `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Recommended", "Popular", "Rock", "Pop", "Blues", "Chill" };
Context context;
private List<Audio> audioList;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context, List<Audio> audioList) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.audioList = audioList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabTitles.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 1:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 2:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 3:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 4:
            return new BlankFragment();
        case 5:
            return new BlankFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}


public View getTabView(int position) {
    View tab = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.custom_text);
    tv.setText(tabTitles[position]);
    return tab;
}

}
```

And I need to get the `List<Audio> audioList` into my Fragment here:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view, container, false);


   //Get auidoList here 

    return rootView;
}
```

I also need to get the `title` of the `tab` in the future but my guess is that I would get it similarly to the `audioList`. If it is not then I could also use help on getting the `tab` title.

Additionally if the code style is wrong then I am always happy to have some feedback on it aswell.

Comment: Is your list is parcelable?

Comment: @Chol If I understood parcelable correctly then no, it is not. The list consists of Audio objects and is an ArrayList. But I could have understood parcelable incorrectly.

Comment: Audio object contains only parcelable data (String, int ...)?

Comment: @Chol yes it does, `Audio(String data, String title, String album, String artist)`

Comment: See Luke's answer then

Comment: I've rolled this back to the last good question state #3, and wonder if it really should be rolled back to #2. You're encouraged to add your final solution as a self-answer, but if you overwrite the question, then the answers given below will be made redundant. Future readers will find it hard to learn anything since there is no longer a question.

Comment: I've rolled this back to #2, since the new question state #3 did not have an answer. It was answered in chat and then not copied back to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional way of doing this is by having an instance method that moves it all via a bundle.

Like this:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String title, ArrayList<Audio> audioList) {

        BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Title", title);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("AudioList", audioList);

        blankFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return blankFragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private String title;
    private ArrayList<Audio> audioList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            title = bundle.getString("Title");
            audioList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("AudioList");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view, container, false);


        //Get auidoList here

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Obviously your `Audio` class will need to implement `parcelable` for this to work. I found a great plugin (Android Parcelable Code Generator) in Android Studio for generating parcelable code that makes that quick and easy.

Comment: In your adapter call the fragment: return BlankFragment.newInstance(tabTitles[position], audioList);

Comment: So I managed to make the Audio list `parcelale` and added what @LukeWaggoner said but I do not get where do I add the return statement into the adapter. At the moment the audiolist that i get is empty.

Comment: Instead of case 0:
            return new BlankFragment();

Comment: @Chol it cannot resolve newInstance and the only option it gives me is to make a new innerClass into Fragment called newInstance. Is that what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: No, normally should be fine, the newInstance method is public static ...

Comment: I had to remove `new` in the line `return new BlankFragment()`. It gives no errors now but I still get an empty list, though it might be my fault so I will try to understand what is the problem here. <br>
Thank you both a lot.

Comment: I checked it in every possible situation and it always creates the list. It seems that it is just not passing it along to a fragment. I have added all that I have been told here. What else can I do?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have now? In your `switch` statement, you'll need to do `return BlankFragment.newInstance(title, audioList)` in order for it to properly be added to the Fragment.

Comment: @kataroty Go here and I'll help you out: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/167755/passing-a-list-from-the-mainactivity-to-a-fragment?tab=general

Comment: @LukeWaggoner: it's an important feature of this site that answers given correlate with the questions asked. Thus, if the question author fixes a problem and this uncovers another problem, they should probably be encouraged to ask a new question. Your answer here was invalidated by the edit to the question, which makes it hard for future readers to learn anything. Also, the new state of the question is not answered. I will remedy this by rolling back the question to its first state, but it'd be great if you could bear this in mind for future multi-part questions. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer Edited my answer.

Comment: I don't think that was necessary @Luke - I was responding to your request to the OP to update the question to what I think was essentially a new question. Is your new answer a response to the question as it stands now, given that I rolled it back to an earlier version before? I don't know this technology, so I will defer to your expertise. If you think it is more useful to roll the question back to #3 then please do - be guided with whatever you think would be most useful for future readers `:-)`.

Comment: Of course, if you want to amend the question to encompass both versions #2 and #3, and edit your answer correspondingly, then go ahead - but that might be a lot of work for too little return!

Comment: My change to the answer actually answers the original question now. The answer as I had left it didn't actually fix his problem. We figured it out in chat, but I didn't copy over the solution.